# Reliably monitor a serial port (Nortel CS1000)

Tags: mysql, linux, logging, serial-port

I have a custom python script that monitors the call logs from a Nortel phone system.  This phone system is under extremely high volume throughout the day and it's starting to appear that some records may be getting lost.

Some of you may dislike this, but I'm not interested in sharing the source code or current method in any way.  I would rather consider this from a "new project" approach.

I'm looking for insight into the easiest and safest way to reliably monitor heavy data output through a serial port on Linux.  I'm not limiting this to any particular set of tools or languages, I want to find out what works best to do this one critical job.  I'm comfortable enough parsing the data and inserting it into mysql that we could just assume the data could be dropped to a text file.

Thank you

Comment: Can you be sure the data isn't being discarded in the phone system BEFORE going out on the serial line?

Comment: If you want to do this temporarily as a cross-check on your script, then just piping it into a text file sounds good.  If you want to run it eternally, something that would split it by date like system logs are might make sense.  Most free software licenses require you to provide source to binaries which you distribute, including to partner entities, but not to ones which you merely use internally, though there are some that require source if you use the program to provide network services - read the terms carefully, and plan for future needs.

Comment: @Chris, I didn't mean I'm trying to have a closed source application to distribute.  This is just a one-off job for the company only.  Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Many Free Software licenses would permit you to privately modify the program as long as you don't distribute it.  But this could cause problems in the future if management insufficiently aware of this constraint makes some kind of alliance with a partner and expects you to share your solutions with them.  Traditionally that's a problem that money can fix simply by buying more licenses - here, money can't fix it, only releasing the code or finding a different solution would.

Comment: @andyortlieb: the solution must use python?

Comment: Also @Chris, regarding your eternal variety, would it make sense to try accomplishing this at the shell level, or would you recommend a C or Python process to do this?  I think I like the idea of dropping to text files that get rotated, or renewed on some sort of timed basis.

Maybe it would even make sense to drop a rotation of log/backup files in conjunction with writing to a pipe for the parser to wait for, since only one process can listen to the serial interface.

Comment: @ass3mbler, I have no preference at this point

Comment: Maybe the first thing you should do is grab another computer and write a tool to generate a flood of fake call records over serial for stress testing, and then something to analyze your files to see if any are missing.  I think that personally I'd be most comfortable coding up the logging in C, but the answer could be different for others.  I think that i might also do some research on how the system logs work before I started, either to see if I could leverage that mechanism, or simply learn from it.  For one way communications you can even make a Y cable to feed two separate computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the way that I would approach this this to have 2 threads (or processes) working.

**Thread 1**: The read thread

This thread does nothing but read data from the raw serial port and put the data into a local buffer/queue (In memory is preferred for speed).  It should do nothing else.  Depending on the clock speed of the serial connection, this should be pretty easy to do.

**Thread2**: The processing thread

This thread just sleeps until there is data in the local buffer to process, then reads and processes it.  That's it.

The reason for splitting it apart in two, is so that if one is busy (a block in MySQL for the processing thread) it won't affect the other.  After all, while the serial port is buffered by the OS, the buffer size is limited.

But then again, any local program is likely going to be way faster than the serial port can send data.  Serial transfer is actually quite slow relative to the clock speed of the processor (115.2kbps is about the limit on standard hardware).  So unless you're CPU speed bound (such as on an Arduino), I can't see normal conditions affecting it too much.  So your choice of language really shouldn't be of too much concern (assuming modern hardware).  Stick to what you know.